# What does the representative mention mean in Coref

Tags: stanford-nlp

See link:
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/faq.html#what-is-the-format-of-the-xml-output-for-coref

In the XML output for coref, there is a mention labelled representative which can either be true or false. what does that mean? Are the nouns true and pronouns false?

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about how "representativeness" is calculated by looking at `edu.stanford.nlp.coref.data.Mention#moreRepresentativeThan`.

In short, you want to choose the "best" mention.  So for instance "Barack Obama" is a more complete mention than "Obama."  How this is calculated is represented in that method.